# How can I highlight syntax of a visible <script> element?

Tags: html, syntax-highlighting

I have this html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yandex.st/highlightjs/7.3/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="http://yandex.st/highlightjs/7.3/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('code script').each(function(i, e){hljs.highlightBlock(e)});
  });
</script>
<style>
  code script{display:block}
</style>
<body>

<pre>
  <code>
    <script>
      // javascript stuff to be highlighted
    </script>
  </code>
</pre>
```

How can I **highlight the syntax** in the last `<script>` element?

It works if I use`$('pre code')` and I remove the `<script>` element.

Answer (score -1):

You need to give your script a type,

example

```
type="text/javascript"
```

Comment: It does not work adding the type. I always obtain as a result `<span class="comment">// javascript stuff to be highlighted</span>`

Comment: Most, if not all, browsers assume that a `<script>` without a type attribute is meant to be Javascript. Also, this answer might have been better off as a comment (though I realize you can't comment yet).